# Using SpEL as annotation value

Tags: kotlin, spring-el, aspect

It's my annotation class:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class ExternalCallMonitor(val system: String, val function: String)
```

Using SpEL to set annotation value as follows;

```
    @ExternalCallMonitor(system = "#{@url.getHost()}", function = "#{@url.getPath()}")
    fun methodWithUrlParameter(url: URL) {
        // Do nothing
    }
```

Trying to get value in the Aspect as follows

```
@Around("@annotation(aspect.external.ExternalCallMonitor)")
@Throws(Throwable::class)
fun externalCallMonitor(joinPoint: ProceedingJoinPoint): Any? {
    val methodName = joinPoint.signature.name
    val signature = joinPoint.signature as MethodSignature
    val method = joinPoint.target.javaClass.getMethod(signature.method.name, URL::class.java)
    val annotation = method.getAnnotation(ExternalCallMonitor::class.java)
    val host = annotation.system
```

`host` should be `localhost` here but I am getting `"#{@url.getHost()}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `BeanExpressionResolver` (e.g. `StandardBeanExpressionResolver`) to process the SpEL.